# Will async-generators that don't have 'await' in its finally-block be immediately closed when there is no reference to it?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, cpython

According to [this blog](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#cleanup-in-generators-and-async-generators), normal generators will be immediately closed when there is no reference to it. (CPython exclusive though). My question is "Does this apply to async-generators that don't have 'await' in its finally-block?"

### Motivation

I'm an auther of an async library, and want async-generators to work like the normal ones. Otherwise, the user have to code something like this

```py
    agen = async_generator_function()
    async with async_closing(agen):
        async for v in agen:
            if some_condition:
                break
            do_something()
```

instead of this

```py
    async for v in async_generator_function():
        if some_condition:
            break
        do_something()
```

Which is pretty annoying. Luckly its [unit test](https://github.com/gottadiveintopython/asynckivy/blob/3b15a9a7a124c0bef38cc39f6bb67629b6284931/tests/test_rest_of_touch_moves.py#L50-L98) always works as I expected so I want to know if it's guaranteed or not.

### Investigation

The following code

```py
import asyncio

async def agen_func():
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            yield i
    finally:
        print('finalized')

async def main():
    async for i in agen_func():
        print(i)
        if i > 2:
            break
    print('end of main()')

asyncio.run(main())
```

printed

```
0
1
2
3
end of main()
finalized
```

And the following code

```py
import trio

async def agen_func():
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            yield i
    finally:
        print('finalized')

async def main():
    async for i in agen_func():
        print(i)
        if i > 2:
            break
    print('end of main()')

trio.run(main)
```

printed the same, which looks like both `asyncio` and `trio` say "NO" to my question, because if async-generators were closed immediately as I expected, they would have printed `finalized` before `end of main()`. Actually, if you use those two async libraries, the answer to my question probably is "NO".

But here is an interesting thing. If you don't use them, async-generators work as I expected.

```
async def agen_func():
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            yield i
    finally:
        print('finalized')


async def main():
    async for i in agen_func():
        print(i)
        if i > 2:
            break
    print('end of main()')


try:
    main().send(None)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

```
0
1
2
3
finalized
end of main()
```

And this is how the async library I'm currently developing works.

#### set_asyncgen_hooks

According to [PEP525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#finalization), `asyncio` does some hacky stuff called `sys.set_asyncgen_hooks()`. `trio` does it too. I believe this is the reason why async-generators don't work as I expected under them. And it's understandable because it's necessary for the async-generators whose finally-block contains `await`.

### more precise question

So my question is:

If you are using CPython, and the async-library you are using doesn't do the hacky stuff above, then async-generators that don't have `await` in its finally-block will be immediately closed when there is no reference to it?

#### environment

- CPython 3.8.1
- Trio 0.17.0